# TemplateSyntaxError: Variable 'user.profile.photo' is an invalid source

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-3.1

I have problem with accessing by the link. I am using easy-thumbnail framework, and I created simple view for user list to list all existing users.
Error message:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Variable
> 'user.profile.photo' is an invalid source.

Django Traceback throws me to this view.

views.py file:

```
@login_required
def user_list(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    return render(request,
                  'account/user/list.html',
                  {'section': 'people',
                   'users': users})
```

urls.py file:

```
path('users/', views.user_list, name='user_list'),
```

template list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block title %}People{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>People</h1>
  <div id="people-list">
    {% for user in users %}
      <div class="user">
        <a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}">
          <img src="{% thumbnail user.profile.photo 180x180 %}">
        </a>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}" class="title">
            {{ user.get_full_name }}
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

sample code from base.html:

```
 <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
 <a href="{% url "user_list" %}">People</a>
</li>
```

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/',
                              blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile for user {self.user.username}'
```

Thank you for the helping in advance.

Comment: models.py class added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewed the documentation https://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#templates. Creates a thumbnail from an object (usually a file field). I tried it and it helped solve my problem:

```
 <img src="{{ user.profile.photo.url }}">
```

Comment: I was in trouble in exactly the same situation, but this solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. You can solve the problem with the following solution:

1. Instead of `users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)`, use `profiles = Profile.objects.all()`
2. Change as follows: `return render(request,'account/user/list.html',{'section': 'people', 'profiles': profiles})`.
3. In the `list.html` file, change as follows:

   ```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}
   {% load thumbnail %}

   {% block title %}People{% endblock %}

   {% block content %}
       <h1>People</h1>
       <div id="people-list">
           {% for profile in profiles %}
               <div class="user">
                   <a href="{{ profile.user.get_absolute_url }}">
                       <img src="{% thumbnail profile.photo 180x180 %}" alt="{{ profile.user.last_name }}">
                   </a>
                   <div class="info">
                       <a href="{{ profile.user.get_absolute_url }}" class="title">
                           {{ profile.user.get_full_name }}
                       </a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           {% endfor %}
       </div>
   {% endblock %}
   ```